# SQL geography::EnvelopeAggregate output not accurate

Tags: google-maps, sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the geography::EnvelopeAggregate for a set of locations. The geography column values are calculated using the Lat/Long for individual points. When I try to fetch the boundary box(Extent) the box does not cover all the individual points. Is this expected behaviour? Can someone who has expertise in this field provide some inputs. Below is the SQL code and corresponding Map plotted. SQL2014 is being used in this example.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..[#ServicePoints]'))
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Points
    END
CREATE TABLE #Points
(
    PointId nvarchar(max),
    Lat float,
    Long float,
    Location geography
)
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point1', 47.659226, -117.218292, geography::Point(47.659226, -117.218292, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point2', 47.659226, -117.218292, geography::Point(47.659226, -117.218292, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point3', 47.659226, -117.218292, geography::Point(47.659226, -117.218292, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point3', 47.658276, -117.218474, geography::Point(47.658276, -117.218474, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point3', 47.658323, -117.21899, geography::Point(47.658323, -117.21899, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point3', 47.658341, -117.219487, geography::Point(47.658341, -117.219487, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point3', 47.660115, -117.219365, geography::Point(47.660115, -117.219365, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point3', 47.658478, -117.216265, geography::Point(47.658478, -117.216265, 4326))

select * from #Points
--select geography::Point(47.658323, -117.21899, 4326)
Select E1.ID, 
                   E1.SPEXtents.STPointN(3).Lat as BottomLeft_Lat, 
                   E1.SPEXtents.STPointN(3).Long as BottomLeft_Long,
                   E1.SPEXtents.STPointN(1).Lat as RightTop_Lat,         
                   E1.SPEXtents.STPointN(1).Long as RightTop_Long, 
                   E1.SPExtents.STPointN(2).Lat as BottomRight_Lat,
                   E1.SPExtents.STPointN(2).Long as BottomRight_Long,
                   E1.SPExtents.STPointN(4).Lat as TopRight_Lat,
                   E1.SPExtents.STPointN(4).Long as TopRight_Long

        from
        (SELECT 1 as ID,
                geography::EnvelopeAggregate(sp.Location) AS SPExtents
        FROM #Points sp
        ) E1;
```

And the representation of these points in map is below. As can be seen 2 points are lying outside the boundary. 
[image: 2 points are lying outside the boundary.]

Or Should I be plotting a circle in which case all points will fall within the circle as shown below.[image: Circle plotted.]

Comment: There is no location possible south of the South Pole. If you enter coordinates in {longitude, latitude} order (X,Y) , the geography datatype won't give you errors. In the future, please be sure to specify the exact PostgreSQL and PostGIS vetsions in use.

Comment: @Vince: Sorry I couldnt understand your comment. Can you please elaborate what I am doing wrong? The coordinates are valid coordinates. And I dont get any errors from SQL. But when I plot the envelope coordinates 2 points are lying outside that. And I dont use PostgreSQL or PostGIS.

Comment: No, they are ***not*** valid if you flip the order. "Point(47.659226, -117.218292, 4326)" does not exist, but "Point (-117.218292, 47.659226, 4326)"  does. Always specify the software in use, so we don't have to giess which database you're using. "SQL" is a language, not a product.

Comment: @Vince: Let me know if the question is not clear. I couldnt get an answer in stackoverflow. You are my only hope.

Comment: The question is clear. Now look again at my comments. You are using the constructor incorrectly; SO should have noticed that.

Comment: @Vince: When I try like this Point (-117.218292, 47.659226, 4326), SQL server throws error mentioning Latitude should be between +90 and -90. Which means what I have originally given should be correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69961/discussion-between-ckv-and-vince).

Comment: Argh! You need to specify "Microsoft" early in the question. The product in use is **Microsoft SQL Server 2014**. Microsoft uses non-standard coordinate order. Someone else can write an answer (or find the previous one) that explains how geodetic rectangles use great circle routes; if you plot the "rectangle" coordinates on a beach ball with string you'll see why the result you requested is the correct one.

Comment: @Vince: So you mean the result is correct. In that case will the 2 points which are lying outside the rectangle also appear outside the rectangle plotted in the beach ball using strings? Since I am new to this area I am asking these questions.

Comment: Could you make a test also with geometry type?

Comment: I don't know why the eastern point is outside, but the northern point *isn't* outside the box, because the line drifts (or should drift) north along a great circle route in the northern hemisphere.